# Sending email with CodeIgniter using 'mail' or 'sendmail'

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, sendmail

I built an intranet app that needs to send email (low volume). I will not be able to use the SMTP server of my organization, so I need to send these emails via `sendmail` or `mail`.

However, when I config my email as:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
```

I get:

```
Exit status code: 127
Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

and when I use:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
```

I get:

```
Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

Is there anything I should setup in PHP or check in `phpinfo()` to figure out how to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried simply not configuring anything? This works most times. If that doesn't work, then I'm guessing the problem is in the `$config['mailpath']` variable.

Comment: do a google search with `codeigniter email settings site:stackoverflow.com` and see if any of the existing questions/answers help you.

Comment: I've been searching for a solution but nothing is specific so far - I need only to SEND email, and everything I find suggests building an email server that can send and receive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK - this was simple.

For anyone who faces this issue:

1. First check if sendmail (actually Postfix) is installed. I am using Ubuntu 11.x.

> cd usr/sbin/

1. If you can't find sendmail, then it needs to be installed

> ```
> sudo apt-get install postfix
> ```

1. I accepted the default options on the dialogs and once install was complete, emails sent without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In windows os , i have tried sendmail class.
You have to put sendmail.exe,sendmail.ini, and other two .dll files inside,

> C:\wamp\sendmail

configure sendmail.ini file as follow for gmail server :

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=mymail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword
hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

then edit your php.ini file, that is available inside

> C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin

```
sendmail_path="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

Now run your project, see log files at:

> C:\wamp\sendmail\error.log
>   C:\wamp\sendmail\debug.log

i think this post can help you..