# sendmail fails on CodeIgniter but works on CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, centos, sendmail

I have sendmail installed on a CentOS 6 server that seems to work well given that I can send a test message using CLI.

However, when trying to send a test message using CodeIgniter's email class, there seems to be some problem. My email.php config is

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']  = "\r\n";
```

The controller for testing email:

```
    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'from name');
    $this->email->to('someone@somewhere.com');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

When I send the test message through CodeIgniter, I get this error message

```
Exit status code: 71
Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

When switching to SMTP or mail in the config I still get errors.

Any suggestions where to start trying to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: `$this->load->library('email', $config);`

Comment: Have you loaded email.php config file?

Comment: Facing similar problem. Getting exit status 64. Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings. But works on CLI

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
  $this->load->library('email');
                $config['protocol']='smtp';
                $config['smtp_host']='your host';
                $config['smtp_port']='465';
                $config['smtp_timeout']='30';
                $config['smtp_user']='your mail id';
                $config['smtp_pass']='your password';
                $config['charset']='utf-8';
                $config['newline']="\r\n";
                $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
                $this->email->initialize($config); //intializing config array 
                $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Site name');
                $this->email->to('someone@somewhere.com');
                $this->email->subject('Mail');
                $this->email->message('Your message');
                $this->email->send();
```

Comment: what are "your mail id" and "your password" supposed to be? those for my server or something specific for SMTP? i don't recall setting up any user/pwd for SMTP

Comment: @torr it will be your email_id and password

Comment: I'm sorry anmol but I don't follow, can you explain further

Comment: @torr did you set smtp_host in config array??

Comment: @torr refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652991/sending-email-with-codeigniter-using-mail-or-sendmail

Answer (score 0):

```
 $config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => '******@gmail.com',
'smtp_pass' => '**********',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset' => 'utf-8',
'wordwrap' => TRUE
 );           
        //send email with #temp_pass as a link
       $this->load->library('email', $config);
       $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('**********@gmail.com', "Title");
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject("Added");

        $message = "<p>This email has been sent as a request to added</p>";
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these.

1. Make sure apache is added to smmsp group.

   id apache

If note add to group

```
usermod -g smmsp apache
```

2. chmod -v 2755 /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail
3. change config['mailpath'] to /use/sbin/sendmail.sendmail

If these tweeks didn't work,

4. chmod 777 /var/spool/clientmqueue
   Its a security risk [link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/470663)